Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'templates_empty_title')
In Wordpress, I have the following error during editing page in backend
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'templates_empty_title')
    at ElementorCommonApp.translate (common.min.js?ver=3.15.3:3:159255)
    at Editor.translate (editor.min.js?ver=3.15.3:3:568743)
    at ./assets/admin/src/template-library/LibraryTemplatesEmpty.js (elementor-modal.js:1:14611)
    at n (elementor-modal.js:1:110)
    at ./assets/admin/src/template-library/LibraryCollection.js (elementor-modal.js:1:5481)
    at n (elementor-modal.js:1:110)
    at ./assets/admin/src/template-library/LibraryLayoutView.js (elementor-modal.js:1:11415)
    at n (elementor-modal.js:1:110)
    at ./assets/admin/src/template-library/Component.js (elementor-modal.js:1:2039)
    at n (elementor-modal.js:1:110)

Could you show me how could investigate more and solve the problem
thank you in advance

It seems like it's attempting to reference undefined.templates_empty_title. If that's in your code directly, find where you are referencing templates_empty_title` and figure out why the element is undefined. If it's in WP code, you're likely passing a reference that leads to an element being undefined.

In the theme Aheto (no more supported) I changed in js file
From this:
ui:{
    title:".elementor-template-library-blank-title",
    message:".elementor-template-library-blank-message"},
    modesStrings:{
        empty:{
            title:n.a.translate("templates_empty_title")
            message: n.a.translate("templates_empty_message")
        },
    noResults:{
        title:n.a.translate("templates_no_results_title"),
        message:n.a.translate("templates_no_results_message")
    },
    noFavorites:{
        title:n.a.translate("templates_no_favorites_title"),
 }      


    
    

to this:
ui:{
    title:".elementor-template-library-blank-title",
    message:".elementor-template-library-blank-message"},
    modesStrings:{
        empty:{
            title:"empty",
            message:"empty"
        },
    noResults:{
        title:"no result",
        message:"no result"
    },
    noFavorites:{
        title:"NO favorites",
        message:"NO favorites"
    }
}

Now it is working
thanks
